# What is the difference between the "appropriate-questions" and "on-topic-off-topic" tags?

Tags: support, tags, meta

When I was adding a tag to another question, I noticed there are two tags that apparently have similar meanings: [appropriate-questions](/questions/tagged/appropriate-questions) and [on-topic-off-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic-off-topic).

When should those tags be used?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the lack of response here, perhaps these tags should not be used at all?

Comment: I can see a use for a tag about appropriate questions; I still don't understand what the difference between those two tags is.

Comment: Jeff, are you saying that we shouldn't have a tag on meta to discuss site scope and what's on- or off-topic? Or are you saying that we should just do a merge (which I would support)?

Comment: @wai I was just remarking that this question fell between the cracks so the tags can't be that important, whatever you want to do is fine with me